# Failure to add content (/node/add/recipe) instead says "This page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500"

Tags: nodes

I am trying to add a node (/node/add/recipe), but it doesn't get saved. Instead, I get the following error message.

> This page isn't working
>   localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
>   HTTP ERROR 500

I get no log messages associated to this attempt to add content. I went into `node_save()` to see how far it went, and it appears to stop near the beginning at `$transaction = db_transaction();`.

I have output `$node` to look for any clue.

Any suggestions on things I could try would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things you could try to debug the issue, as it appears limited to just this one "recipe" content type on your site (presuming you have a local running copy of the site):

1. Enable php error logging in your site's settings.php as described here https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/show-all-errors-while-developing
2. Flush your Drupal cache, then try adding a recipe node.
3. Upon saving, you should see php errors output to the browser, and you can `tail` the apache logs.  This should help you further narrow down the cause of the error.

More than likely, one of the following is the culprit on saving your content:

- There's a reference type/entity/field whose dependency has been accidentally deleted or modified (sometimes a machine name change, or settings change to a field widget can cause this, especially if there was data already present in that field)
- A database field table has been corrupted/accidentally changed or deleted.  This can happen if you installed some updated modules/Drupal core code without properly running updates from the *"Run Updates"* menu link or via `drush updatedb`
- If you're uploading image(s) as part of the content, make sure they are optimized for the web and not gigantic in dimensions. Overly large images can freeze up/lock up on image cache generation due to limited memory.